# Fixed length Gaussian pdf

Tags: probability

In a research problem about detection theory I faced with the following question.
How can I find the conditional Gaussian probability density function

$$ f({\mathbf w} \; | \; \|{\mathbf w}\|^2)$$
where $\mathbf w$ is  an $N$ dimensional random vector with Gaussian distribution  with Zero mean and co-variance matrix $\mathbf I$ ($N\times N$ identity matrix) and also $\| {\mathbf w}\| $ is the 2-Norm of vector $\mathbf w$?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

In two dimensions, it is easy to see that $\|{\mathbf w}\|^2=w$ is a circle of radius $w$. considering that the Gaussian distribution with the given $\mathbf I$ is rotationally symmetrical, we may say that the conditional distribution given is uniform over the circle centered at the origin (the means are $0$s).

Generalizing this intuition, I suspect, that the conditional distribution in question is uniform over the surface of the suitable hyper sphere.

**EDIT**

The distribution is uniform over the $(n-1)$-sphere in the $n$ dimensional Euclidean space. The surface of the $(n-1)$-sphere centered at the origin is described by

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=w^2.$$

[The surface area of the same is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area)

$$V_n(w)=\frac{\pi^{\frac n2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac n2+ 1\right)}w^n.$$

So, the distribution is $$\frac1{V_n(w)} \text{ if } \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=w^2, 0\text{ otherwise .}$$

See also [Marsaglia's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Uniformly_at_random_within_the_n-ball).

Comment: Thank you for your hint, your intuitive answer seems to be correct. Yet, we need a closed form answer for the pdf. For example it seems that for $N=1$ the answer is dirac delta function.

Comment: (Two Dirac delta functions, at $-w$ and at $+w$...).  OK, I will give "the technical answer."